# How to install Conda Virtual Environment without using sudo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sudo, conda

I am running anaconda2 (condo 4.3.15) on Mac Yosemite. I am trying to create a python2 condo environment. However, when I try to crate an conda virtual environment, I get the IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied as follows:

`$ conda create --name  datasci python=2.7 numpy pandas scipy matplotlib scikit-learn nltk ipython-notebook python-igraph

```
Fetching package metadata ...An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues




Current conda install:

               platform : osx-64
          conda version : 4.3.15
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.15
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.13.final.0
       requests version : 2.12.4
   naconda_client.py", line 40, in read_binstar_tokens
        with open(tkn_file) as f:
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/Users/xxxxx/Library/Application        Support/binstar/https%3A%2F%2Fapi.anaconda.org.token `
```

It seems the new version of conda needs always sudo. Even for doing 'conda update conda.

Just to mention that I have installed Anaconda ( for python 2.7) for single user.

Any help would be much appreciate it.

Comment: Try deleting the folder `/Users/xxxxx/.continuum`